# Java Recursion to Return Object with Max Element

Tags: java, arrays, object, recursion

For a class project, I must return an object in an array that has the maximum value in weight using a recursive method. I can't get the correct output for the life of me. The method is returning the Packet object at the exact index that is passed when the method is invoked in my main method. This is the code I have for the method.

```
public Packet maxWeightPacket(Packet[] list, int n) {
    Packet max = new Packet(0, 0.00, "");
    if (n == 0) {
        return list[n];
    } else {
        if (list[n].getWeight() > max.getWeight()) {
            max = list[n];
        }
        maxWeightPacket(list, n - 1);
    }
    return max;
}
```

Code for Packet Class is here:

```
public class Packet {
    private int idNumber;
    private double weight;
    private String destination;

    public Packet(int idNumber, double weight, String destination) {
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public boolean isHeavy() {
        if (weight > 10)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return idNumber + " " + weight + " " + destination;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

}
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: your `else` block completely ignores the return of the recursive calls - so the returned `max` will always stay the one assigned in the first call (which is the index you passed in)

Comment: @Os."n" is the length of the list. I thought that was the issue, but I have no idea how to keep track of the Packet with the largest length and return it. I cannot instantiate any Packet object to track that outside of the maxWeightPacket method per the project restrictions.

Comment: @JMarotta can you include within your question that the method signature can't be changed since that's the case.

Answer (score -1):

Since you can not change the method´s signature, what you can do is:

```
public Packet maxWeightPacket (Packet[] list, int n )
      {
        Packet pack = new Packet (0,0.00,"");
        if (n == 0)
        {
          return list[n];
        }
        if (list[n].getWeight() > list[n-1].getWeight())
        {
              pack = list[n-1].getWeight();
              list[n-1].getWeight() = list[n].getWeight();
              list[n].getWeight() = pack;
              maxWeightPacket(list, n-1);
        }
      }
```

So, you will always keep the greatest weight at list[n-1] till the last recursion call

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the method signature by adding any additional parameters.

Comment: check the new solution @JMarotta

Answer (score -1):

`Packet max = new Packet (0,0.00,"");` seems to be the problem.

You are defining new max packet in each recursive call.

What you should do is define `Packet max` OUTSIDE of `maxWeightPacket` method.

Change your code to following :

```
Packet max = new Packet (0,0.00,"");
public static Packet maxWeightPacket(Packet[] list, int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return max;
    } else {
        if (list[n].getWeight() > max.getWeight()) {
            max = list[n];
        }
        maxWeightPacket(list, n - 1);
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: The project is restricted so that I cannot define any other Packet object in class Recursion, where the maxWeightPacket method is. Everything must be done inside that method.

Comment: Can you change method signature?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The method signature must be: public Packet maxWeightPacket(Packet[], int n)

Comment: So what part of code can you change other than inside of `maxWeightPacket` method? Can you add another method?

Comment: Personally, I think it is not okay to give a negative just because you have constraints and can not make it happen. The answer works just find if you can edit the code

Comment: Nothing haha. I can only change the code inside of maxWeightPacket.